# How to identify the item when using a script

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

I have generated a rule which then actions a SCRIPT.

I want to get details from the identified email message - i.e. the body then output to a file that can be read elsewhere.

My logic sort of works but I am currently retrieving the contents of the selected or highlighted email rather than the email identified by the rule.

INFO ONLY
[Specifically the email is a FOREX Signal with a defined Subject.  I then want to get the contents of this email to a file that can subsequently be read by an Expert Advisor running on a MetaTrader 4 platform]

struggled to get meaningful tags accepted - i.e. script or OutlookRules

Answer (score 0):

You pass the mailitem as a parameter.

If, for example, you pass Item then process **Item**.

```
Sub CustomMailMessageRule(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
   MsgBox "Mail message arrived: " & Item.Subject
End Sub
```